# internet problem (DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET)

Tags: networking

I was a windows user until I recently changed my os to fedora and it worked fine but I didn't like the navigation there and it seemed awkward so I changed to ubuntu 20.04 lts yesterday it was working fine but today I started getting a weird problem first the wifi icon changed to question mark one and there was no internet so I restarted the wifi and it worked again but after some time it stopped and I got the DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET error on chrome so I thought maybe the problem is with the dns and changed it too but nothing and every time I restart the wifi it works for a minute or two then stops
I don't understand what is the problem and why it is only on ubuntu
by the way I used firefox and there is no internet and I did some commands to test some stuff out

```
    wget -O /dev/null google.com
    --2021-06-02 16:46:58--  http://google.com/
    Resolving google.com (google.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘google.com’

ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlo1 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlo1 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlo1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.106 metric 600

ping -c4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.106 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.106 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.106 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.106 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3071ms
pipe 4

host google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] you question and add `ip a` outputs (1) when Internet is working and (2) when it is not.

Answer (score -1):

it turn out that the problem is the power saving system
my wifi card is Ralink corp. RT3290
so if you have the same problem try [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=318580)